# AngularJS HTTP use response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vis.js

Hello this is my second time using AngularJS... I create a http request and no problem with it.
But the question is, how i can get the result of this request or put in a variable ?

```html
var cust_url = "RETURN A JSON";    
var FINAL_FILE = "";

$http.get(cust_url)
    .then(function (response) {    
        $scope.details = response.data;   
        //--> do multiple modify to response.data      
        FINAL_FILE = 'something';
    }); 

$scope.data = {   
    /*USE HERE --> FINAL_FILE       
    return -> undefined on console if i try to access to FINAL_FILE
    */
};
```

Like the example... sorry i think is a stupid error. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$http` request is asynchronous, this is the reason that you get the undefined value. If you want to use the response data, you have to do it inside the `then` callback, where the data are available, like this:

```
$http.get(cust_url)
    .then(function (response) {

        $scope.details = response.data;

        //--> do multiple modify to response.data  

        FINAL_FILE = 'something';

        // here use the $scope.details or call a function to use data

        $scope.data = { };

});
```

Comment: Thaks you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Return data to the `.then` method and save the promise:

```
var finalFilePromise = $http.get(cust_url)
.then(function (response) {    
    $scope.details = response.data;   
    //--> do multiple modify to response.data      
    FINAL_FILE = 'something';
    return FINAL_FILE;
});
```

To use, extract the data from the promise:

```
$scope.data = {   
    //USE HERE --> FINAL_FILE       
    finalFilePromise.then(function(FINAL_FILE) {
        console.log(FINAL_FILE);
    });        
};
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - Chaining Promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises)